# Current User name is not showing on page refresh

Tags: angularjs, node.js, jwt

I am login with username and password using JWT in angular js.
I am able to save token and currentUser in angular cookies as below:

```
 $scope.login=function(){  
    $http.put('/api/login', $scope.loginUser).then(function(response){
        $cookieStore.put('token',response.data.token);
        $cookieStore.put('currentUser',$scope.loginUser.name);
        $rootScope.token=response.data.token;
        $rootScope.currentUser=$scope.loginUser.name;  
        $location.path('/dashboard');
       }, function(err){
       alert('Bad Login Credentials');
      });
      };
```

Its successfully working. But now on client side I am showing currentUser after successfully login.

```
<span ng-hide="currentUser">
      <li><a href="#/login">Login</a></li>
      <li><a href="#/register">Register</a></li>
      </span>
      <span ng-show="currentUser">
      <li style="color:#fff">Hi, <span style="color:green">{{currentUser}}</span></li> 
      </span>
```

and it appears like below:
[image]

But problem is that whenever I refresh the page using `f5` and `ctrl+R` the currentUsername replace with token id like below in image.[image]

Please suggest me solution and why its happening.

Thanks,

Comment: CurrentUser is not in the scope after refresh. Read the cookie instead

Comment: but `currentUser` is in `$rootScope`

Comment: It is just when you do login() then scope becomes empty when refresh

Comment: Yeah.. I got `app.run()` function `app.run(function($rootScope, $cookieStore){  
 if($cookieStore.get('token') && $cookieStore.get('currentUser')){
        $rootScope.token=$cookieStore.get('token');
        $rootScope.currentUser=$cookieStore.get('currentUser'); 
  }
})` now its working fine